# iOS - Bad Access when calling ALAssetsLibrary several times

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access, alassetslibrary

When a user uploads a picture from the iPhone gallery, I extract the location using `ALAssetsLibrary`:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [assetslibrary assetForURL:urlPhoto
                           resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                               CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
                           } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                           }];
```

However, if the user uploads a picture and then returns to the upload screen and upload another, after three or four uploads the app crashes on `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, when running the `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` method.

I guess it happens since the `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` runs async and the `ALAssetsLibrary` is released for some reason, though it cannot run simultaneously the way I've built the app.

How can I prevent it from crashing?

**EDIT**

Although the crash was always at this point (due to the earlier dismiss), the error occurred because of a `UITableView` that was deallocated earlier, but at this point referred to its delegate/datasource.
the fix was adding:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    myTableView.dataSource = nil;
    myTableView.delegate = nil;
}
```

at the end of the `UIViewController` that had the TableView.

Comment: on which line do you get the error ? on the assetLibrary = ? or the callback ?

Comment: can you try putting your callback on the main queue ?

Comment: I've added logs to see where it crashes, as only caught in main. seems it starts running the assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock: method, but never gets to the callback methods.

Comment: tried to do the callback on the main thread, changing the result to be performed on main thread: `[assetslibrary assetForURL:urlPhoto
                           resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                               [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkLocation:) withObject:asset waitUntilDone:YES];
                           } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                           }];`
still crashed...

Answer (score 1):

Just change your object to property .

interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary;
```

Than call implementation:

```
if (self.assetslibrary == nil) {    
    self.assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
}
[self.assetslibrary assetForURL:urlPhoto
                           resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                               CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
                           } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                           }];
```

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't work. According to the NSLog's I have the allocation of the ALAssetsLibrary doesn't fail. It happens when running the method assetForURL, before entering the callbacks.